# EigenvalueType’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using eigen library for a finding `eigevalues` and `eigenvectors`. From [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html#a50d070013a795db5621119f2b4a3d781) webpage the following definition-:

```
const EigenvalueType & eigenvalues () const;
```

Hence I am using a statement like

`const Eigen::EigenvalueType &value = solver.eigenvalues()`

The following files have been included:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions"
#include "Eigen/Eigenvalues"
```

I also checked the [source code of the file](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/EigenSolver_8h_source.html) containing the `typedef` for `EigenValueType` and included it too with statement:

```
#include "Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/EigenSolver.h"
```

But still I am getting the following error at compile time.

```
error: ‘EigenvalueType’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a type
```

I do not understand why it is not able to recognize the typedef's. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EigenvalueType is a typedef declared inside class `EigenSolver`, you need to use it like

```
  Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd>::EigenvalueType &value = solver.eigenvalues()
//^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Alternatively he could do a `using namespace EigenSolver;` inside his own namespace. (Note that `using` any namespace in a header file, inside the global namespace is considered bad practice)

Comment: I have edited the answer so that it compiles. I understood the mistake I was making and did this for completeness's sake.